# Converting HDF5 to GeoTIFF using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, hdf, nasa

I'd like to convert a subset from HDF5 to GeoTIFF

The data is OMPS Aerosol Index data (EarthData login to download)
https://snpp-omps.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/SNPP_OMPS_Level2/OMPS_NPP_NMTO3_L2.2/2019/211/

I'm expecting an eventual output of this https://acd-ext.gsfc.nasa.gov/People/Seftor/OMPS/world_2019_07_21.png

I've tried these methods from other Answers but the command line just stops and doesn't give any errors.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff ‘HDF5:"OMPS-NPP_NMTO3-L2_v2.1_2019m0724t000444_o40089_2019m0724t020831.h5”://ScienceData/UVAerosolIndex’ omps.tiff
```

and

```
for %A in OMPS-NPP_NMTO3-L2_v2.1_2019m0730t013311_o40175_2019m0730t054038.h5 do gdal_translate -of GTiff -sds "%A" "%A.tiff"
```

This is the output from gdalinfo for the subdataset I'm interested in

```
 SUBDATASET_32_NAME=HDF5:"OMPS-NPP_NMTO3-L2_v2.1_2019m0730t013311_o40175_2019m0730t054038.h5"://ScienceData/UVAerosolIndex
```

Comment: Do we really need to see your full gdalinfo output which is causing this to be automatically flagged as too long?  I think you should try cutting it down to just enough to get across what you are trying to show.

Comment: Im happy to cut it down but don’t know which part is important.

Comment: Then I would try taking a guess.  Potential answerers will soon let you know if you have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a problem with your usage of quotes. Try this (single quotes removed).

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:"OMPS-NPP_NMTO3-L2_v2.1_2019m0724t000444_o40089_2019m0724t020831.h5"://ScienceData/UVAerosolIndex omps.tif
```

Also make sure your gdal supports the HDF5 format with

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

Comment: That does work without fail! The output isn't what I expected, its just a few trajectory lines by the look of it, but I guess thats a different question. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Marking my answer as a solution would be much appreciated, as I need those couple of reputation points to be able to upvote answers :D